# IOS 6 navigationController navigationbar

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, ios6, addsubview

I just updated my phone to IOS 6 but I have some issue regarding adding UIImageView on the UINavigationController navigationbar. This is my code

```
UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar.png"];
UIImageView *logoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:logoImage];
UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
[navBar addSubview:logoImageView];
[logoImageView release];
```

This will add logo on navigationbar, it works great on the lower version of IOS 6. But on IOS 6 the logo shown but **the back button was behind the logo so back button is not shown.**

I don't want to override the UINavigationBar drawrect since I also have UINavigatioBar somewhere on the code for popup.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need a `UIImageView` in IOS 6.

You can just put a background image in the `UINavigationBar` (for example in `AppDelegate`) like this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage :[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationbar"]];
```

Found a good site which explains some new user interface customisation in IOS 6:

[click here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6)

Comment: Add: `... forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault`